# Webkit any overwrites user agent stylesheet

Tags: html, css

I manually specify the h1 font-size in my stylesheet:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 1.5em 0;
}
```

Locally this works just fine, but as soon as I transfer my stylesheet to the browser, Dev Tools shows me:

```
:-webkit-any(article,aside,nav,section) h1 {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  margin-block-start: 0.83em;
  margin-block-end: 0.83em;
}
```

and

```
h1 {
  font-size: 2em; <--- this is crossed out
}
```

This is a problem in Chrome only, Firefox works without problems both locally and on the server.
I deferred the loading of the stylesheet via:

```
<noscript id="deferred-styles">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</noscript>
```

and

```
<script>
var loadDeferredStyles = () => {
    var addStylesNode = document.getElementById("deferred-styles");
    var replacement = document.createElement("div");
    replacement.innerHTML = addStylesNode.textContent;
    document.body.appendChild(replacement)
    addStylesNode.parentElement.removeChild(addStylesNode);
};
  var raf = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;
  if (raf) raf(function() { window.setTimeout(loadDeferredStyles, 0); });
  else window.addEventListener('load', loadDeferredStyles);
</script>
```

Certain styles in this stylesheet don't get set on the web-presence, like h1, margin of the body, et al. Others however are set just fine: image sizing, fonts (also loaded async), and spacing.

How to fix this?

Comment: You'd likely find that your `h1` is styled the same in Safari, as that is also WebKit based. If you look at the source of the selector, what is it? (In Dev Tools, to the right of the selector, right-aligned, it should show a link to the source of the style, or *user agent stylesheet* if it's part of the browser's stylesheet.)

Comment: it's h1. There is no reason it should be overwritten though IF the style was specified?

Comment: That's not the source stylesheet. See the red-circled items in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91yW1.png).

Comment: The style would be overwritten if the `h1` element is the descendant of any of the elements in the list (article,aside,nav,section), in WebKit-based browsers. See [`:matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:matches), which is the standard name for `:-webkit-any()`.

Comment: Please see for yourself: [stylesheet](https://imgur.com/a/EujmrBi). How do I fix it?

Comment: Add a selector to make it more specific. If you want more specific help, you'll need to show us the HTML for the element.

Comment: Note that image doesn't show you manually specifying `font-size: 2em` in your stylesheet; it shows it as part of the user agent stylesheet, which is overriding itself. If you actually override it in a stylesheet, it will work: https://jsfiddle.net/5jwq0zue/

Comment: It is specified in the stylesheet: [link](https://imgur.com/a/NaeRtmi)

Comment: Well, it's not getting to your browser for some reason. See the link you posted previously [stylesheet](https://imgur.com/a/EujmrBi). Maybe you're seeing an old version of "styles.css"? Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181000/discussion-between-helle-and-heretic-monkey).